# Get data in another page through post

Tags: php, html, forms, post, action

I have been trying to get the value of a variable in another webpage.
On click of the button Confirm, the page should send the value of id to the next page. I am getting the following error -

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''" name = "user_id" >Confirm</' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 57
```

This is where I am trying to send the data.

```
<body>
 <form action="database3.php" method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php
$r=$_GET['ch'];
echo $r;
 echo '<div class="container">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="'.$r'" name = "user_id" >Confirm</button>
 </div>';

 ?>
```

This is where I am trying to fetch the data in database3.php -

```
<?php

 extract($_POST);
  $id=$_POST["user_id"];
  echo $id;

  ?>
```

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: `echo $r;` the ; means you're finishing there and then trying to do something with the html part. Add another "echo" there.

Comment: @LordNeo That echo must have got erased while I was posting. I have edited the code. Kindly see.

Comment: Check also the dot fix of @Arkwosky and check any other error on the log

Comment: you missed the point in `value="'.$r'"...` : should be `value="'.$r.'"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function since this:

> Import variables into the current symbol table from an array. [Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

You should do instead:

```
<?php
    extract($_POST);
    echo $user_id;
?>
```

**Update**

All the variables from the `$_POST` variables are going to be mapped to variables for example:

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue", "size"  => "medium");
extract($var_array);
```

Creates two new variables:

```
$color; // blue
$size;  // medium
```

So in your case `$_POST` has `$_POST['user_id']` it creates the variable `$user_id` than can be used after on any next following code.

Also there is no need to mix `HTML` with `PHP`when you can do:

```
<?php $r = $_GET['ch']; ?>
<div class="container">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $r; ?>" name="user_id" >
    Confirm
  </button>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

The problem looks like is on the HTML you are missing a `.` in order to concatenate accordingly:

```
<?php
$r=$_GET['ch'];
echo $r;
echo '<div class="container">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="'.$r.'" name=      "user_id" >
 Confirm</button>
 </div>';
   ?>
```

Since concatenations between strings and variables inside of single quotes are as follows:

```
$variable_name = 'Hi!';
echo 'The value of a variable is: ' . $variable_name . ' So that was';
```

Alternatively there are better ways to work around this as I mentioned on my example to avoid the mix of `HTML` and `php`. Also there are functions like `sprintf` or `printf` that makes things more expressive:

```
$variable_name = 'Hi!';
printf('The value of a variable is: %s So that was', $variable_name');
```

Comment: That did not work. Also,I want to store the value in a variable so that I can use it later in the code.

Comment: +1 for explaining issues with extract even though it wasn't the cause of the error. Although you did fix the later error with refactor, probably should have explained the cause of error since op missed it.

Comment: Updated with the explanation of the issue.

Comment: Update 2 helped me. It was just a dot that I had missed. Anyway, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code:

```
value="'.$r'"
```

should be code like this:

```
value="'.$r.'"
```

You have missed the dot after variable $r.